# Color set by setColorFilter disappears on prelollipop devices

Tags: android

I have a TabLayout which has icons. The idea is to change the colors runtime.
I have and xml drawable file  with states: state_pressed, state_selected and default with the same white picture so I can put color later. 
I take the drawables for different states:

Drawable[] drawables = stateListDrawable.getConstantState();

and the for every drawable state I put color from another array:

drawables[i].setColorFilter(colors[i], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

The issue is that the color is visible in the beginning, but when I start to click on the icons all the icons becomes white again and I lose the tint.

Everything is working as expected on lollipop and above.

Comment: drawables[i].setColorFilter(colors[i], PorterDuff.Mode.SRCATOP);

Comment: I have tried that. Same result. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution, which does not look clean at all, but at least it is working :)

I have created CustomStateListDrawable which extends from StateListDrawable and added the drawables for the different states. Then I have overridden all the methods in the class to see which ones are called and tried to change the colors there. The called late enough(my changes will not be overridden after I make them) was getState(). I have created also a ColorStateList object to hold my colors so the code will look like this:

```
       private ColorStateList colorStateList;


        public int[] getState() {
                if (colorStateList != null) {
                    // Resolve the color for the current state
                    int color = colorStateList.getColorForState(super.getState(), 0);
                    // Get the current drawable and changed its color. 
                    if (getCurrent() != null) {
                        getCurrent().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    }
                }
                return super.getState();
            }
```

Basically every time when there is a change in the state I get the current drawable and change its color.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tint method from the v4 Support library

```
drawables[i] = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawables[i])
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawables[i], colors[i])
```

Comment: I have tried that. Probably 10 other things. Same result. :)

Comment: Actually I lied. I have tried it second time to be sure. This way the color is not changed at all. The icons are white from the start.